# get the headlines of the authors' last post

Tags: author, get-posts, sort

I want to list my authors with the title of their last post.

ı want to sample sort

**user1, title1, date=19.10.2017 > user2, title2, date=17.10.2017 > user3, title3, date=15.10.2017**

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "
SELECT * FROM wpig_users 
JOIN wpig_posts ON wpig_posts.post_author = wpig_users.ID
JOIN wpig_term_relationships ON wpig_posts.ID = wpig_term_relationships.object_id WHERE  term_taxonomy_id ='11'
ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 10"  );



foreach($results as $res) { 

    //echo $res->col1;

    echo '<b>';
    echo $res->display_name;
    echo '</b> // ';
    echo $res->post_title;
    echo '<br>';
 }
?>
```

I could write a code like this. but this code takes the last posts and authors.

as in the picture

Note : the code I wrote does not list the last writers of all authors.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

WordPress provides its own function to accomplish this:

`get_most_recent_post_of_user( $user_id );`

Source:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_most_recent_post_of_user